# SecurityContextHolder returns a null Authentication object during unit test

Tags: spring-test

I have the following code in a method that I am trying to test in a SpringBoot app.

```
Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();  
String token = (String)authentication.getCredentials();
```

The issue is that the `authentication` object is always null in unit test mode.

My Test method is

```
@Test
public void testMyMethod() {
    // .. prepare other responses
    Authentication authentication = mock(Authentication.class);
    SecurityContext securityContext = mock(SecurityContext.class);
    when(securityContext.getAuthentication()).thenReturn(authentication);
    SecurityContextHolder.setContext(securityContext);
    when(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getCredentials()).thenReturn("a_toke");

    String uri = baseuri + "/myapp";
    this.mockMvc.perform(post(uri).contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).content(sampleRequestWithOneResource))
            .andExpect(status().isOk()).andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.jsonPath("$.status").value("SUCCESS"));

}
```

The POST call above results in the execution of the code that needs to read the  token from the `Authentication` object. The test fails since `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();`returns a null value.

I am not sure what I am missing.

Comment: What happens if you change the "when" line to the following? `when(authentication.getCredentials()).thenReturn("a_toke");`

Comment: That does not work either because `authentication`  is still null.

Comment: OK. What happens if you delete all of your custom security mocking and annotate the test method with `@WithMockUser(password = "a_toke")`?